# How do you know when the reason for a SEM being unidentified is because of the very variables that you put in?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, identifiability, amos

How do you know when a SEM shows as unidentified not because of the path diagram but because of the actual variables that you put in?

The following model is well-identified according to AMOS, but when I simply replace variable X7 with variable X10 (which literally should change nothing), all of a sudden the model is unidentified and I am asked to add 1 constraint.
Also, when I remove X5 and X9 from the model to keep only 2 observed variables per latent, all of a sudden I am asked to add not 1 but 2 constraints.

[image]

All variables have 1000+ observations and are samples of uniform independent distributions.

The very small correlations is the only reason I can think of for the models to fail, but it is not a very satisfying explanation.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The very small correlations in your correlation matrix are indeed a concern. These look like they are correlations between random numbers (many are essentially zero). The correlations are so small that they could lead to empirical underidentification of an otherwise identified model. For example, factor variances depend on there being substantial covariances/correlations between the indicators of that factor. With only two indicators per factor, the situation gets worse.

With such small correlations, it does not seem to make much sense to test any covariance structure model at all (other than a null/independence model). Are you sure the correlations are correct? Could there be a data error?

Comment: Yes they are correct, the variables are indeed random and independent as I simply created a random database to play around and try and understand what makes a model (un)identifiable. I did not bother model the variables on a correlation matrix, but maybe I should have. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Structural equation modeling (SEM) is covariance structure modeling (for the most part). It does not make sense to model covariance structures of independent (uncorrelated) variables. Perhaps generate a data set/covariance matrix by simulating a specific SEM model using Monte Carlo simulation techniques.

Also, Bollen (1989) discusses general SEM identification rules:

Bollen, K. A. (1989). Structural equations with latent variables. John Wiley & Sons. https://doi.org/10.1002/9781118619179

Comment: Yes, I made another dataset since then with a covariance structure that is consistent with what you would expect from data to fit this model, and it does work fine. Still somewhat puzzled that the software gives you the exact same warning message (that is, « your model is unidentifiable ») whether you did not specify enough constraints or your covariance matrix poorly fits the model. These seem to be two quite distinct issues.

Comment: Yes, the message indeed is not very helpful. Empirical underidentification is always something to think of when a theoretically identified model produces such a message.